# How to save Hexa characters in NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, character

I am trying to add Hexa characters in NSArray as given below

```
           [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:0x0C,0xFF,0x46,0x64, nil];
```

But it crashes by stating EXE_BED_ACCESS.Can any one please help how can I save these characters in NSArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not store non-object to Objective-C objects.

You need to convert all those Hexa character to objective-c objects before adding it to array.

Box it to `NSNumber` and then use

```
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(0x0C), @(0xFF), @(0x46), @(0x64), nil];
```

To convert it back, you need to again de-box the number.

```
NSNumber *num = self.array[2]; //here i am extracing only the 3rd object.
NSInteger integerValue = [num integerValue];

NSLog(@"%X",integerValue);
```

Comment: `@0x0C, @0xFF, ...` will work too. "(" and ")" are needed only when boxing variables

Comment: then how can i get back the character , when i retrieve its changed to f0 70 a0 60? please help

Answer (score 0):

just put @ infront of the HEXA characters

```
NSArray *ArrayName = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@0x0C,@0xFF,@0x46,@0x64, nil];
```

it is tested n working fine no crashes at all.